# Why does my x64 program crash silently on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, crash, windows-7-x64, undefined-behavior

Consider this little program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    *((int *) 0) = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, writing to $0 causes a memory access fault. When compiling this program as a 32-bit executable with Visual C and running it Windows 7 clearly shows that the program has crashed: (German system)

[image: Screenshot]

When compiling the program as a 64-bit executable with Visual C, however, it just crashes silently. No system dialog pops up that informs the user that the program has just crashed.

Is that normal behaviour for x64 binaries or is there something wrong with my Windows 7 configuration? I think the operating system should clearly show to the user when programs crash instead of just killing them silently...

***EDIT***: For all people claiming that the compiler might just optimize the null pointer access away, here's the assembly. You can see that the illegal memory access is in there and it is also shown in Windows' application log after running the program.

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 

include listing.inc

INCLUDELIB LIBCMT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  main
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
_TEXT   SEGMENT
argc$ = 8
argv$ = 16
main    PROC
; File d:\test.c
; Line 2
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rdx
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+8], ecx
; Line 3
    mov DWORD PTR ds:0, 1      ; here we go folks
; Line 4
    xor eax, eax
; Line 5
    ret 0
main    ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

***EDIT 2***:  I have also verified that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI` is set to 0. So Windows is explicitly configured to report crashes. But it only does so for x86 binaries, not for x64 binaries. Yes, for x64 binaries the crash is reported in the application log but the error dialog (see screenshot above) only shows up for x86 binaries and not for x64 binaries although `DontShowUI` is clearly set to 0.

***EDIT 3***: I have made tests on different Windows systems. Here are the results:

```
Windows 7: x86 shows crash dialog, x64 doesn't (as described above)
Windows 8: both x86 and x64 show the crash dialog
Windows 10: neither x86 nor x64 show the crash dialog
```

So the only system which behaves inconsistently here is actually Windows 7. On all other systems the crash dialog is either shown or not whereas on Windows 7 there is a different behaviour between crashes of x86 and x64 programs. Weird.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with my VS 2017. What happens if you debug the program in x64 mode?

Comment: "Is that normal behaviour", again asking about the behavior of undefined behavior don't make sense. "Obviously, writing to $0 causes a memory access fault." no, that undefined behavior.

Comment: @Stargateur even if it is technically UB, on windows it should crash in both x86 and x64 as it should crash on Linux

Comment: @Jabberwocky No, if NULL is not a valid address, the compiler is allow to do whatever it wants, this include "do nothing". There is no "should" when you trigger an undefined behavior.

Comment: That's the WER dialog, whether or not it shows up is an OS configuration option.  It doesn't anymore by default on Win10 machines btw.  Double-check that you got an event for the crash in the Application log.  Ask about WER configuration at superuser.com.  And consider to just move on, you want to make sure that the debugger can help you diagnose this bug.

Comment: @Stargateur: But it clearly crashes on x64 as well. If you add a `printf("foo\n")` after the write, this will never be printed on x64 so it clearly crashes instead of just ignoring the write op.

Comment: @Stargateur that's true, but at least on my platform the generated code in release mode for this small program is `mov dword ptr [0],1` and this should definitely crash.

Comment: @Stargateur: From a programming language perspective you are correct: Pondering about the potential outcomes of code that exhibits UB is moot. However, a platform can extend guarantees beyond those established by the programming language. On Windows (and consequently any compiler targeting Windows), dereferencing a pointer to an invalid addresss will deterministically trigger an access violation, reported as an SEH exception. Thus, the code in the question exhibits UB as far as the language is concerned, but will still exhibit well defined behavior on Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm sure I can use an invalid address somewhere in the stack that will not trigger any exception on windows still this would be an invalid address from the point of view of C. What I want to said is that the compiler is allow to skip this instruction or worst, there is different version of VS, I agree that windows will trigger a exception when you try to write a "true" invalid address, but what is the rule when compiler didn't do this because it assume that this is not possible ? There is a big difference between runtime guarantee and compilation guarantee. VS is NOT a C compiler

Comment: @sta: Raising an SEH exception in response to writing to or reading from inaccessible memory is part of Windows' ABI. *Any* compiler targeting Windows *must* implement that contract. I decidedly said *"platform"* in my previous comment to mean the combination of OS and compiler. This isn't restricted to Visual Studio. Besides, a pointer into the stack is always valid. Stack memory is accessible. It may not be a pointer to the correct address, but that doesn't mean the OS, runtime, or compiler were required to raise an SEH exception. You are conflating different aspects here.

Comment: Raising an exception upon an invalid access is what the API demands. The API does not demand any particular outcome from writing C code with UB: that’s between you and the compiler, and the contract of the Windows API has zilch to do with it. Many compilers remove everything following a null access and won’t emit any code there – indeed, a dereference of a null pointer literal is one way of telling the modern compiler to stop emitting code.

Comment: @kub: I wasn't referring to the Windows API. I was referring to Windows' ABI. The ABI is not something between me and the compiler. It is a contract between the compiler and the target OS/architecture. A compiler *must* follow that contract.

Comment: @KubaOber - sure that here unrelated to c/c++ rules ub. let OP show asm code and/or change to `*((int *) 1) = 1;`

Comment: @Andreas What happens if you execute the program under a different user on the same computer? And on another computer? If you debug the x64 code, does it break into the debugger with something like `Exception thrown at 0x0000**** in ****.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.` ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: See my latest edit for test results from different systems. Apparently, only Windows 7 shows the inconsistent behaviour. Windows 8 and 10 are consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the code emitted indeed contains the access to memory at address zero, then the binary crashes. Windows is not guaranteed to show a crash message – it can be [suppressed via group policy](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/), for example.

The process itself can constrol it using [`SetErrorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WerRegisterRuntimeExceptionModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/werapi/nf-werapi-werregisterruntimeexceptionmodule). See also [`werapi.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/werapi/).

Comment: My code contains the access to memory at address zero and crashes. I verified Windows' application log which reveals the crash. I have read the article in the link you posted and I have verified that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI` is set to 0. So Windows is explicitly configured to *show* the crash. But it only does so for x86 binaries, not for x64 binaries. Yes, for x64 binaries the crash is shown in the application log but why does the dialog box only show up for x86 binaries when `DontShowUI` is clearly set to 0? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The 64 bit code uses a different flag perhaps. There is also a setting you can make in your own code to explicitly control the Windows crash message behavior at runtime. I don’t have a link handy but perhaps that will help you find it.

Comment: @KubaOber apparently not. At least not on my Windows `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI ` changes the behaviour of x86 and x64 programs.

Comment: There are runtime apis that control this and override the registry.You may want to check from your process if there are WER handlers installed already that may implement this "show nothing" behavior. You may also want to check from your process whether the registry value is the same as you see from the registry editor: it may be different!

Comment: I checked the value of the registry key at runtime, it is 0, so no luck here. Then I checked the return value of `GetErrorMode()`. It is `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` (1) both for x86 and x64. This is weird because it is described as `The system does not display the critical-error-handler message box. Instead, the system sends the error to the calling process` but the error message box *is* displayed when the x86 binary crashes! Next thing I tried was explicitly calling `SetErrorMode(0)` but this didn't change the behaviour either. The error message box still is only shown for x86, not on x64.

Answer (score 2):

WER on Windows 10 never shows a dialog when an invisible process crashes, regardless of the `DontShowUI` value. `DontShowUI` only has an effect on processes that display a user interface. I've looked hard, but couldn't find a similar setting for invisible processes. It seems that WER's silent crash handling in those cases is by design.

So I've written a tool that hooks itself into WER and modifies its behaviour to show the dialog for all crashes, including those in invisible processes: [WerTweak](https://github.com/tdebaets/wertweak). As a plus, it makes WER display the same old-style crash reporting dialog as in previous Windows versions, instead of the crippled new dialog usually displayed in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `*((int *) 0) = 1;`, and therefore your entire program, is *undefined*.

The various crashes are a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

Some compilers may well optimise out your code to `int main{}`: gcc has been optimising out undefined statements on high optimisation settings for a while now. Perhaps that accounts for the 64 bit compilation behaviour?

Comment: It’d be easy to check for this: show a message box after the crashing line. If you get to see it, then the compiler has optimized the access out.

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question that was being asked. The OP has verified, that object code writing to address 0 is being emitted. Whether this is UB when looking at it with language-lawyer-colored glasses makes no difference. The platform has decided to attribute well-defined semantics and reproducible behavior to what is UB if you stop looking beyond the language specification.

Comment: @KubaOber - this can be checked even more easy - use `*((int *) 1) = 1;`. this is already not UB from c/c++. sure result will be the same (of course better look asm code always)

Comment: @kub: That strategy will not prove anything. A compiler is allowed to reorder instructions, if it finds that there is no dependency involved. Seeing a dialog as well as not seeing a dialog can mean literally *anything*.

Comment: @IInspectable I’m assuming that the assembly output is being looked at, and a null access is followed by the message box call.

Comment: @kub: Drawing conclusions from unfounded assumptions isn't going to right the wrong. The assumptions are wrong. It's game over from there. You need to fix the assumptions.

Comment: gcc does not optimize US out. It prevents the program from further execution https://godbolt.org/z/wo9m4A

Comment: @P__J__ clang does and that why it's UB

Comment: See my edit in the OP. Asm code shows the access is right there. The crash is also shown in Windows' application log.

Comment: @Andreas That definitively put your question as off topic, stackoverflow is here to ask about about code, and reasonably tool about programming, for exemple a debugger, but config windows to show a error message is out of scope here.

Comment: @sta: Clang on godbolt doesn't target Windows, so that's a different platform, and it simply doesn't apply to the question asked here. The question also *is* on-topic. It's not asking about how to configure a system, but rather, how the system behaves. An answer to this question will serve as the basis to make decisions on implementing error discovery and reporting in an application. That's clearly a developer-centric Q&A, even if it part of the solution involves changing (global) system settings.

Comment: @IInspectable No this is not, this is the exact same case when asking behavior about a shell. This is out of scope because this error message is not handle by the program not even by the compiler, it's entirely handle by environment system, and that why super user is for.

Comment: @sta: Again, incorrect. Exceptions are handled differently on Windows, depending on whether you run in the WoW64 emulator or not. Insight into that produces information, that's actionable by a developer. It's also something you **cannot** change, so asking this on Super User isn't going to produce any meaningful information.